# Content Disposition inside an HTML document on a Asp.net server

Tags: asp.net, content-disposition

I am trying to make a button, that when clicked, downloads a src defined pdf. The problem I have is when I make a button is that in IE it opens in an embeded reader instead of downloading it. I was advised to use a content-disposition header. I am running on a asp.net server, but I only know HTML, JS, and CSS. My question is how do I implement this?

This is what I think I am supposed to do:
In a file: example.html

```
<!-- begin document -->
<% 
some sort of asp.net code about content disposition goes here
%>
And then my html code goes here
<!-- end document -->
```

Is this the right idea?
And if so, what am I supposed to put for the asp.net code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create a index.html file:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="get_pdf.aspx">Download PDF</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

After, create a get_pdf.aspx:

```
<%
    Response.Clear()
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf")
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
    Response.WriteFile("test.pdf")
    Response.Flush()
    Response.End()
%>
```

And after put you pdf with the others files. You server folder 'll have the following files:

- index.html
- get_pdf.aspx
- test.pdf

Comment: Do I save the file as a html or something else?

Comment: Try it now. =) Any doubt about the answer?

Comment: Its giving me some sort of compilation error. Seems that it doesn't like semi-colons...should I remove those or do I need those

Comment: Which iis are you using? Post here the compilation error. I test this model, and works fine to me, i'm able to download the test.pdf.

Comment: It seems Visual studio added semi-colons at the end of each line, removed them, saved it and it works :) Thank you VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY VERY much :)

Comment: +25 Rep for the answer. Thank you so much for walking me through this. It works great, and I understand how it works, why it works, and how to do it again :)